# Получение данных из базы данных Postgres с использованием Spring + Hibernate (Java)

Tags: spring, java-ee, hibernate, jsp, servlet

Вывод данных в консоль отрабатывает нормально без ошибок:

```
public class Main {

private static final Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(Main.class);

public static void main(String[] args) {

    ApplicationContext context = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("springContext.xml");
    TenderService serviceTender = (TenderService) context.getBean("tenderService");     
    EmailService serviceEmail = (EmailService) context.getBean("emailService");  

    List<Tender> tenderList = serviceTender.getAll();       

    for (Tender tender : tenderList) {
        logger.info(tender.getIdTender() + "\t" + tender.getNameTender());
    }
}
```

SpringContext.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
   xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
   xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
   xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop"
   xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
   xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop-2.0.xsd">

<context:annotation-config/>
<context:component-scan base-package="ru.icl.parser"/>

<tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager"/> 
<!--<tx:annotation-driven mode="proxy" transaction-manager="transactionManager"/>-->

<!--Database--> 
<bean id="dataSource"
    class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
    <property name="driverClassName" value="org.postgresql.Driver"/>        
    <property name="url" value="jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/TenderCatalog"/>
    <property name="username" value="username"/>
    <property name="password" value="p@ssw0rd"/>
</bean>    

<bean id="jpaDialect" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaDialect"/>

<bean id="jpaVendorAdapter"
      class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaVendorAdapter">
    <property name="database" value="POSTGRESQL"/>
    <property name="databasePlatform" value="org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQL9Dialect"/>
    <property name="showSql" value="true" />  
</bean>

<!--Entity Manager--> 
<bean id="entityManagerFactory"
      class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean"> 
    <property name="persistenceUnitName" value="punit" />       
    <!--<property name="persistenceXmlLocation" value="classpath:META-INF/persistence.xml"/>-->        
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource"/>
    <property name="jpaVendorAdapter" ref="jpaVendorAdapter"/>              
    <property name="jpaDialect" ref="jpaDialect"/>
</bean>

<!--Transaction Manager-->     
<bean id="transactionManager"
      class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager">
    <property name="entityManagerFactory" ref="entityManagerFactory"/>
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource"/>
    <property name="jpaDialect" ref="jpaDialect"/>
</bean>

</beans>
```

Но при запуске сервлета возникает ошибка:

```
SEVERE [http-nio-8080-exec-228]
org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke Servlet.service() for 
servlet [ViewTender] in context with path [/ParserTender] threw exception 
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating 
bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in class path resource 
[springContext.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is 
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError:
javax.persistence.spi.PersistenceUnitInfo.getValidationMode()Ljavax
/persistence/ValidationMode; 
at    
org.springframework.beans.factory.support.
AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean
(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1553) 
at
org.springframework.beans.factory.support.
AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.do
CreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:539) 
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.
AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean
(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:475) 
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.
AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:304) 
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.
DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton
(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:228) 
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.
AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:300) 
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.
AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:195) 
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.
getBean(AbstractApplicationContext.java:973) 
at org.springframework.context.support.
AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization
(AbstractApplicationContext.java:750) 
at org.springframework.context.support.
AbstractApplicationContext.refresh
(AbstractApplicationContext.java:482) 
at org.springframework.context.support.
ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.<init>
(ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.java:139) 
at org.springframework.context.support.
ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.<init>
(ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.java:83) 
at ru.icl.parser.servlet.ViewTender.doGet(ViewTender.java:34)
```

Сервлет:

```
   @WebServlet(name = "ViewTender", urlPatterns = {"/view"})
   public class ViewTender extends HttpServlet {          
   @Override
   protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) {

    ApplicationContext context = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("springContext.xml");
    TenderService serviceTender = (TenderService) context.getBean("tenderService");
    EmailService serviceEmail = (EmailService) context.getBean("emailService");
    List<Tender> tenderList = serviceTender.getAll();
    request.setAttribute("tend", tenderList);        
    try {
        request.getRequestDispatcher("index.jsp").forward(request, response);
    } catch (ServletException ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Как с этим бороться, подскажите пожалуйста?

Фрагмент maven-файла pom.xml:

```
<properties>
   <org.springframework.version>4.0.5.RELEASE</org.springframework.version>
    <org.hibernate.version>4.3.5.Final</org.hibernate.version>
</properties>   
<dependencies>
    <!--Hibernate-->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
        <version>${org.hibernate.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
        <version>4.3.1.Final</version>
    </dependency>
    <!--Spring Framework-->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-jdbc</artifactId>
        <version>${org.springframework.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-orm</artifactId>
        <version>${org.springframework.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <!--Other Libs-->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.persistence</groupId>
        <artifactId>persistence-api</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
        <version>4.0.3.RELEASE</version>            
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax</groupId>
        <artifactId>javaee-web-api</artifactId>
        <version>7.0</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

Comment: покажите, пожалуйста, конфиги билд-тулы (maven, gradle)

Comment: Добрый день, Etki. Конфиг файл pom.xml добавлен выше.

Comment: Попробуйте целиком убрать hibernate-core. hibernate-entitymanager сам по себе объявляет зависимость на core, и в текущем варианте их версии расходятся. Предположу, что entitymanager ожидает версию 4.3.1, а видит версию 4.3.5, в которой уже нет ожидаемого класса, поэтому он не может его загрузить.

Comment: Убрал из pom.xml hibernate-core, ошибка осталась

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/22178613/2908793 вам нужна вторая версия persistence-api, а у вас используется первая

Comment: После команды "mvn clean" все заработало. Спасибо за помощь, Etki.